# Empty response from Roads API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the Google Roads API to find the GPS coordinates of the closest point on a road from a given point. It only completes the request for the first given point (`"originalIndex": 0`); can anyone explain why? My API key is valid, and I can locate the second point on Google Maps and see a nearby road. When I request the second point by itself, I receive the empty response "{}".

Request:

https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/nearestRoads?points=60.170880,24.942795|-0.030331,30.513929&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Response:

```
{"snappedPoints": [
{
  "location": {
    "latitude": 54.9702813818773,
    "longitude": -1.6113525033160663
  },
  "originalIndex": 0,
  "placeId": "ChIJicwBW7ZwfkgRQJjXzwd96mM"
},
{
  "location": {
    "latitude": 54.9702813818773,
    "longitude": -1.6113525033160663
  },
  "originalIndex": 0,
  "placeId": "ChIJicwBW7ZwfkgRQZjXzwd96mM"
}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second point (-0.030331,30.513929) is too far from the road. In that case the API the documentation says it will return an empty response ("If there are no nearby roads, no segment is returned.")

Comment: What is the distance threshold for "no nearby road"?

Comment: Couldn't find it in the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

The distance between your point and the road should be within 50-60 meters. If this distance is bigger the service returns empty response.

In your example the point `-0.030331,30.513929` is far away. You can check it with geocoder tool:

https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D-0.030544%252C30.514678

You will see that distance is bigger than 50 meters.

[image]

If I select a point closer to the road, for example `-0.027619,30.51668`, the nearest road endpoint will return results

`https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/nearestRoads?points=-0.027619%2C30.51668&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

The similar issue was reported before in the public issue tracker:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37843707

I hope this addresses your doubt.